# Best practice for data streaming #bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, real-time-data

How would you go for real time data streaming from a PostgreSQL DB on GCS to BQ?
Google has literally a ton of options and products on the left panel menu and from what i could find online, i saw that Datastream and Dataflow might be the way, but that example I found is with data from an oracle DB.
Would a database already on GCS only need dataflow?
I'm confused, the available material doesn't say much (at least to me, maybe it's my limitation) and i need to find a solution as I'm totally new to Google products.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Please look at this https://medium.com/google-cloud/stream-your-data-on-prem-ms-sql-to-cloudsql-sql-server-to-bigquery-part-2-47057e9e2637 . This talks about data movement from on Prem to gcp first. However, you can ignore that. Rest things you can relate too.